# Deserialize json array in web api project

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-web-api

My controller method is as follows

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Tweets model = null;
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var task = client.GetAsync("http://localhost:33615/api/product").ContinueWith((t) =>
    {
        var response = t.Result;
        var readtask = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Tweets>();
        readtask.Wait();
        model = readtask.Result;
    });
    task.Wait();
    return View(model.Result);
}
```

The url return the row as follws:

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"Honda Civic","Description":"Luxury Model 2013"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Honda Accord","Description":"Deluxe Model 2012"},{"Id":3,"Name":"BMW V6","Description":"V6 Engine Luxury 2013"},{"Id":4,"Name":"Audi A8","Description":"V8 Engine 2013"},{"Id":5,"Name":"Mercedes M3","Description":"Basic Model 2013"}]
```

My Tweets and tweet class are as follows:

```
public class Tweets
{
    public Tweet[] Result;
}
public class Tweet
{
    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I can't figure it out where i do mistake.it gives me following error:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'RestFiddlerTest.Controllers.Tweets' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly
```

How to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

I've double checked your code and there are a few issues with it.
First of all, I don't see your logic to deserialize to Json, according to the JSon object, I'm guessing that you're using Newtonsoft.Json?

Then you have a class `Tweets` which contains an array of `Tweet` objects.
Now, when you create a small sample, like the following:

```
var dataToSerialize = new Tweets();
dataToSerialize.Result = new [] { new Tweet { Description = "Desc", Name = "Name" } };
var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataToSerialize);
```

The output of this piece of code will be the following:

```
{"Result":[{"Id":null,"Name":"Name","Description":"Desc"}]}
```

This is not the same as the output you get from your WebAPI.

Now, when you do use Newtonsoft.Json, when serializing your object, you are probably doing something like this:

```
const string JSon = "[{\"Id\":1,\"Name\":\"Honda Civic\",\"Description\":\"Luxury Model 2013\"},{\"Id\":2,\"Name\":\"Honda Accord\",\"Description\":\"Deluxe Model 2012\"},{\"Id\":3,\"Name\":\"BMW V6\",\"Description\":\"V6 Engine Luxury 2013\"},{\"Id\":4,\"Name\":\"Audi A8\",\"Description\":\"V8 Engine 2013\"},{\"Id\":5,\"Name\":\"Mercedes M3\",\"Description\":\"Basic Model 2013\"}]";
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tweets>(JSon);
```

**Note: I've put the Json string in a string because I didn't have the time to write a full WebAPI.**

Now, this will not work, because the string I input and that's also the one that your controller does return is not a `Tweets` object (remember you're missing the `Result` in your JSon string? Instead, this is a array of `Tweet` objects, so you can change your code like the following:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tweet>(JSon);
```

Unfortunately, you will receive the exact same error. So why is that? Because you're trying to deserialize your object into an object of type `Tweet` while your object is an array of type `Tweet`.

So, modify your code like the following:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tweet[]>(JSon);
```

Now, you're deserializing your object into the correct type.

[image]

So, I do hope that this post will help you.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 2):

I used Newtonsoft.Json.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Tweet> model = null;
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var task = client.GetAsync("http://localhost:33615/api/product").ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            var response = t.Result;
            var readtask = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Tweet>>();
            readtask.Wait();
            model = readtask.Result;
        });
        task.Wait();
        return View(model);
    }
```